# How do I build a form with embedded view results

Tags: forms

I need to create a sign up form that also displays all of the submitted values above each value on the same page.  I have searched for hours and cannot find anything that describes how to achieve this. 
So it would be formatted like:

Sign Up Form

Results of value 1:

value1, user 1

value1, user 2

value1, user 3

[enter value for value1] <= this is the form field to enter a new value1 for current user

Result of value 2:

value2, user 4

value2, user 2

value2, user 6

[enter value for value1] <= this is the form field to enter a new value1 for current user

[submit]

I have come close with webform and building a webform-form--nid.tpl.php file to override the default template, and use views to create tables for the results but the view tables are listing all of blank fields as well.  I have tried entitfyform but don't know how to split up the form to allow to have the views above each relevant section.

Answer (score 0):

Sign Up Form

```
<?php
    function formfun_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['formfun'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'FORM FUN',
    'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('formfun_form'), //put the name of the form here
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,

    'access callback' => TRUE
  );
  return $items;
}

function formfun_upload_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['add'] = array(
 '#type' => 'fieldset',
'#title' => t('Add company details'),
);
  $form['add']['companyname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' => 'Company Name',
  );

  $form['add']['contactname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' => 'Contact Name',
  );

    $form['add']['companyaddress'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' => 'Contact Address',
  );

    $form['add']['postalcode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Postal Code',
  );

    $form['add']['city'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'City',
  );

    $form['add']['country'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Country',
  );

    $form['add']['file'] = array(
        '#type'     => 'file',
        '#title'    => t('Choose a file'),  
);

  $form['add']['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Here!'),

  );
   return $form;
}

function formfun_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    echo '<pre>';
var_dump($form_state['values']);
echo '</pre>';

    db_insert('details')
    ->fields(array(
    'companyname' => $form_state['values']['companyname'],
        'contactname' => $form_state['values']['contactname'], 
        'companyaddress' => $form_state['values']['companyaddress'], 
         'postalcode' => $form_state['values']['postalcode'],  
        'city' => $form_state['values']['city'],  
         'country' => $form_state['values']['country'],  
         'image' => $form_state['values']['file'],
   ))
   ->execute();
    drupal_set_message("successfully saved Security Settings"); 
    exit();
}

function formfun_validate($form,&$form_state) 

{
  }
```